# Youtube video iframe not loading on product page

Tags: magento-2.1, product, product-video, youtube

Have a lot of products with videos on the product page, but the videos are not loading. The thumbnail is displayed, but when I click on it I get the following error:

> ```
> load-player.js:64 
> Uncaught
> {name: "Video Error", message: "Unknown video type", toString: ƒ}
> ```

The youtube videos are not recognized as youtube videos I guess,  does anybody have a idea where this problem lies?

Answer (score 0):

Its probably caused by scope of video. Magento 2 now is not supporting scope in media (issue is reported [here](https://github.com/magento-engcom/community-features/issues/23))

Videos data is related with scope so if you add video on scope of store 1 in store 2 you have thumbnail and no video data which cause javascript error.

Workaround for that is to add video as All Stores View and it will be accessible in all scopes.

Code reference for that issue is in:

```
\Magento\ProductVideo\Model\Plugin\Catalog\Product\Gallery\ReadHandler::afterExecute
```

and video data is stored in table:

```
catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value_video
```

you can try fix scopes in this table (just change store_id to 0)